# How to avoid casting SwiftUI views to AnyView when passing them in as a parameter to a function?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using `UINavigationController` under the hood for my SwiftUI application since `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` are extremely limited and/or buggy. I have a function called `pushView(..)` that needs to take in a SwiftUI view, wrap it in `UIHostingController` and then push it on top of the navigation stack:

```
func pushView(view: AnyView, animated: Bool = true) {
    let hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    navigationController.pushViewController(hostingView, animated: animated)
}
```

Now, most of my calls look like `...pushView(AnyView(MyView())`, I have to cast every single view to `AnyView` which is a bit annoying and unclean.

Is there a better way to do this so I don't have to cast every single time?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd need an `AnyView` to type-erase views if you want to collect them into some array (rare, for SwiftUI, and unless you know what you're doing, it's probably not the way to go), but here since all you're doing is pushing instances of `UIViewControllers` (which is what `UIHostingController` inherits from), you should be able to use a generic function:

```
func pushView<V: View>(view: V, animated: Bool = true) {
    let hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    navigationController.pushViewController(hostingView, animated: animated)
}
```

```
pushView(view: MyView())
```

Comment: Thanks! When would I need to use type erasure specifically?

Comment: @Zorayr, updated the answer. There are some cases, but they are rare