# How to avoid using `AnyView` type erasure in closures for callback, in SwiftUI?

Tags: generics, swiftui, swiftui-list, type-erasure, swiftui-scrollview

I'm trying to create table views based on both `List` and `ScrollView`, with a shared base view. My current attempt uses a builder-based approach, but requires closures with `AnyView` type erasure.

My goal is to avoid using `AnyView` type erasure, to improve performance, scalability, and design.

My attempts to re-design with generic type parameters have so far failed.

The simplified (and working) code example below displays only a single `String` column, but captures the basic challenge. (In actuality, these are multi-column tables with various data types, specialized formatters, modifiers, etc.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ListTable(title: "My List", data: data)
            ScrollTable(title: "My Scroll", data: data)
        }
    }
}

struct ListTable<T: Hashable>: View {
    var title: String, data: [T]
    var body: some View {
        BaseTable() { header, row in
            VStack {
                header(title)
                List(data, id: \.self) { row($0) }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollTable<T: Hashable>: View {
    var title: String, data: [T]
    var body: some View {
        BaseTable() { header, row in
            VStack {
                header(title)
                ScrollView { ForEach(data, id: \.self) { row($0) } }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BaseTable<Content: View, T: Hashable>: View {
    typealias HBuilder = (String) -> AnyView
    typealias RBuilder = (T) -> AnyView
    var builder: (@escaping HBuilder, @escaping RBuilder) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        // NOTE this is where I'd like to avoid type-erasure to AnyView
        builder({ AnyView( Text("Header \($0)") )},
                { AnyView( Text("Row \(String(describing: $0))") ) })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View { ContentView() }
}
```

Two related questions that didn't quite provide a solution:

- [65810765](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810765/how-to-create-a-struct-parameter-that-is-a-closure-with-input-returning-some-v) - How to create a struct parameter that is a closure with input, returning `some View` instead of `AnyView` in SwiftUI?
- [64655195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655195/how-to-avoid-casting-swiftui-views-to-anyview-when-passing-them-in-as-a-paramete) - How to avoid casting SwiftUI views to AnyView when passing them in as a parameter to a function?

Comment: If you know the result of the `BaseTable` builder, why not just explicitly define the types? `HBuilder = (String) -> Text` then return `Text`?

Comment: Look at `SwiftUI.LazyVGrid` interface design - it actually fits table concept.

Comment: jnpdx: that works for the header in the example, but ideally the builders support other types through a generic parameter, such as Toggle, Picker, TextField, or other type.

Comment: asperi: in my implementation I make extensive use of LazyVGrid in the header/row builders, but I stripped them from the single-column example for clarity. However, I'll experiment with using them as the basis for the explicit type.

Comment: UPDATE: my first attempt to use LazyVGrid as the explicit view type failed, as it requires a view type parameter. (AnyView works here too, but doesn't solve the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a working answer to my own question.

Creating a 'wrapper' view for the row, which will serve the explicit type used in the row builder closure:

```
// new 'wrapper' view, which can contain Text, LazyVGrid, etc.
struct RowView<T: Hashable>: View {
    var value: T
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row \(String(describing: value))")
    }
}

// update to original BaseTable
struct BaseTable<Content: View, T: Hashable>: View {
    typealias HBuilder = (String) -> Text
    typealias RBuilder = (T) -> RowView<T>
    var builder: (@escaping HBuilder, @escaping RBuilder) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        builder({ Text("Header \($0)") },
                { RowView<T>(value: $0) })
    }
}
```

Thanks to the commenters!